# how improve the python 3 load time

Tags: python

In the doc's there is a explanation of the pyc files that are generated when a library is imported.  This was confusing to me.  When I run my script starting with a py file (actually small 500 lines) the load time is long.  However, if I move the pyc files to the primary folder the load time is greatly reduced ( I have to rename them) because in the pycache folder there is an added string to the name "310" for example.  You would think that 500 lines would load fast and the libraries would also load fast too since they were pyc files.
Either I don't understand or in fact the pyc files are not being loaded.
I have one script that is taking a long time to load.  When run the script from the command line using the py file it appears to take longer than if I run the script from the command line using the pyc file after moving the pyc files from the pycache folder.

The question is - is that just my imagination or is it real.  Yes I know there are tools to time the load but I can't get them to work correctly.

Thanks in advance,
Johnf

Comment: Not your imagination, that's just how Python works. Very poor research effort if that is your question.

Comment: Well, I couldn't prove it until I was able to get the time tool to work.  When I removed all the pyc files from __pycache__ folder indeed it was slower.  After, of course,the pyc were there and load time improved (not completely sure of this).  But moving the pyc file to the primary folder and starting the script using the pyc file and not the py file proved to be even faster.  Improved by almost a full second.

Comment: There is also something going on that does not make sense to me.  How is it possible that pyc in pycache folder are not loading as fast as the same files placed in the same primary folder.  I'm running ubuntu 22.04, python 3.10.x.  I doubt there would be any issue with running any file from a sub-folder causing any noticeable time difference.  Could it be because some are in the site-packages.  But then why would moving the pyc to the primary folder be any different?  I also left all the py files in the primary folder.  I do open a database connection (using a model).

Comment: Is the timing code causing the issue?  Drawing on straws here.  Any thoughts would be helpful.   All it do is print(time).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a tool to time the load times and indeed the load is faster.
Johnf